# Typehint inherited class variables in PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm

In PHPStorm, I can type-hint a variable this way:

```php
/** @var Point $point */
$point->x();
```

However, say I inherited a variable from a parent class, and want to type-hint it:

```php
class PointProxy extends Proxy
{
    public function x()
    {
        ...

        /** @var Point $this->geometry */
        return $this->geometry->x();
    }
}
```

This doesn't work, PHPStorm acts as if I had type-hinted `$this`, and not `$this->geometry`.

Is there a way to make such a type-hint work *without redeclaring the `$geometry` property in the subclass*, or is this unsupported?

Comment: You cannot use such PHPDoc for complex (2nd level in hierarchy) objects -- only first level. This `/** @var Point $this->geometry */` makes no sense .. as PHPDoc comment will be applied to first level (`$this` in this case) only. Right now you may try to declare it via `@property` in PHPDoc comment for the class  -- should only make sense if it's a public property and not private/protected.

Comment: If at all possible the property should be type hinted in the parent class; this should propagate through to child classes.

Comment: @deceze It *is* type-hinted in the parent class, but as `Geometry`. The child class should document that it is in fact a `Point`, descendant of `Geometry`.

Answer (score 11):

Try this code. Also you can press `alt+enter` at undefined properties and select `Add @property` it will help you to create phpdoc faster.

```
/**
 * @property Point $geometry
 */
class PointProxy extends Proxy {
  public function x() {
    return $this->geometry->
  }
}
```

[image: add property]
[image: completion]

Comment: The problem with `@property`, as mentioned by @LazyOne, is that the property is considered `public`, which is not the case here, and might bring confusion!

Comment: If this property is virtual and dynamic (we access it via `__get`) - it is `public` in real. If you want to make it `protected` or `private` declare it in class.

Comment: It *is* protected in the parent class!

Answer (score 0):

If the parent object types the property as Geometry but you want it typed as a Point (which descends from Geometry) in your child class, I would recommend creating an accessor in your child class. Possibly with some type checking.

```
class PointProxy extends Proxy
{
    /**
     * Access the geometry object on parent class as a Point
     *
     * @return Point
     */
    private point()
    {
        if(!is_a($this->geometry, 'Point'))
        {
            // Log an error or something, this is not a state we should be in
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->geometry;
        }
    }

    public function x()
    {
    ...

        return $this->point->x();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a very similar problem. I had a generic storage class that dealt with database operations and then a proxy class on top which proxied all storage class methods through a try catch (using `__call()`) so that I could handle exceptions in one location.

Now whenever I accessed the storage instance like `$storage->retrievePhoto($id)`, the PHPStorm IDE could not typehint for me. My solution involved adding another class name annotation to the `$storage` object.

For example, see below. Since the specific proxy class is really just a wrapper over the original storage class, it doesn't present any problems although it is still not 100% to my liking but it works.

```
final class PhotoRepository
{
    /**
     * @var \Repositories\Photos\PhotoStorage
     *      \Repositories\Photos\PhotoStorageExceptionHandlerProxy
     */
    private $storage;

    /**
     * @param \Repositories\Photos\PhotosStorageExceptionHandlerProxy $storage
     */
    public function __construct(PhotosStorageExceptionHandlerProxy $storage)
    {
        $this->storage = $storage;
    }
```